NASM : _malloc allocating too much memory
I am trying to use dynamic allocation in assembly under macosX, and I have encountered a rather strange behavior while calling _malloc from the C library.
My final goal would be to allocate something like 10 bytes in memory, but when writing data outside of the allocated chunk, the program doesn't segfault.
Maybe I don't understand how _malloc works.
This is the test code I wrote. I tried first to push the size on the stack as Christopher Swenson seems to do. Then I read this post that seems to say that the size should be in rdi. As the latter is more recent, I assumed it was also the most right.
extern _malloc ;; malloc from the C library
section .text
    global _start

_start:
  xor rdi, rdi
  mov rdi, 10         ;; I try to allocate 10 bytes
  call _malloc        ;; The address should be in rax
  mov qword [rax], 1  ;; writing some data where it is supposed to work
  add rax, 11         ;; going outside the allocated chunk
  mov qword [rax], 1  ;; writing some data where it is not supposed to work

  mov rax, 0x2000001
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall

For simplicity purpose, I don't test rax, assuming it is not NULL.
I compiled with :
$ nasm -f macho64 -o test.o test.asm
$ gcc -e _start test.o -lc -m64 -o a.out -Wl,-no_pie

Could someone please explain how I don't use _malloc properly or why writing outside the allocated chunk does not segfault ?

You're not guaranteed a segfault at all. You're not even guaranteed it will cause a problem somewhere down the line.

When you allocate memory with malloc and the allocation succeeds, you are guaranteed to have that memory you allocated be accessible.  However, there is no guarantee that other memory is inaccessible.  It's just not guaranteed to be accessible.  So do not rely on that.
In practice, malloc asks the operating system for large chunks of memory at a time and then parcels these chunks out to the various small allocations you make.  So it's very common to see that there's more memory accessible than you allocated.  However, that memory must not be used, it doesn't belong to your allocation.  Instead, malloc is likely to give that memory to future allocations.  It may also be used for other purposes, such as bookkeeping.  So don't access it.

The MMU cannot protect memory at the byte level.  It protects pages, the size of which is hardware and OS dependent.  4 Kbytes is probably typical.
Also while OS dependent, and I would not know the details on MacOS, typically the MMU protection would be applied at the process level, not the individual allocation level. So you get a page fault only when accessing memory outside of your process.
The process requests memory from the OS which will be provided in page sized chunks or multiples thereof, and that memory is added to the process's heap, at which point the entire heap belongs to the process and if the process overruns an individual allocation but remains within the process's memory, it will not be detected as a page fault, because it isn't one.
In some cases (in a debug build perhaps), if the overrun corrupts the heap management metadata if another allocation, that may be detected by the runtime when the associated allocation is free'd. But it may not be obvious which allocation overran, only which was corrupted.  But it is undefined behaviour regardless.
To achieve what you are expecting the MMU would require a page size of 1 byte, which is impractical.  The MMU page table could end up needing to be larger than the memory it was trying to protect!

typically the MMU protection would be applied at the process level, not the individual allocation level - IDK what hypothetical alternative you're even considering.  Like that the CPU would track how a pointer was derived, so [rax + rcx] could fault if outside of the allocation containing rax, even if the resulting address was inside another valid page?  (Kind of like how C rules make it UB to access outside the object a pointer was derived from.)  Anyway, as you say, allocation works by mapping pages in your process's virtual address-space so they're backed by RAM instead of faulting.

"IDK what hypothetical alternative you're even considering" "hypothetically" thread stacks within a process might be separately protected for example.  I have no idea whether that is done on MacOS.  I did not want to be too empathic as I don't know ( or care).

Oh, with each thread having its own page tables?  Yeah that would be hypothetically possible (with more work for the OS and more TLB invalidation on switching between threads of the same process), but would break C because in C it's legal to store a pointer to a local variable in something globally reachable, which lets other threads access your stack memory (unless an implementation didn't use the asm stack for automatic storage). It's also irrelevant for malloc which can't allocate on the stack since the allocation has to live past the function returning (or even this thread exiting).

@PeterCordes I was proposing the stack be separated from the heap and static/global so the process has the heap and static/global, while each thread has its own stack.  So the page table has fixed heap and global regions and dynamically switches the stack region. I work for in embedded systems with RTOS kernels where everything is a thread, no process model, and those that support an MMU certainly do that or similar.

Yeah, that's what I thought you were saying, although I didn't know RTOS systems actually did things that way.  That would make it impossible to do things that are legal in  C and C++, like having a local std::atomic<int> stack_var = 1; on the stack and doing shared_var = &stack_var; for other threads to read and/or write your stack memory.  Since mainstream OSes like macOS and Linux do support ISO C's thread model, they need all threads of a process to share the same memory map (page tables).

@PeterCordes typically stack protection is optional per thread, and shared memory would typically be statically allocated.  There is much that is legal in C that is not suited to safety-critical or high-integrity embedded systems.  Conceptually the application and RTOS are one and the same program and the kernel is simply a static link library.  As such accessibility is in the hands of the developer at the application layer.

Sure.  You wondered if mainstream desktop OSes like macOS do the same thing.  And one reason why not is that it would be a showstopper for the thread-aware memory models of mainstream languages.  (Or more realistically, those threading models are designed that way because OSes already worked that way, with threads of the same process all sharing the same page tables.)
